# Sketch $M=\{re^{i\phi}:r\in(1,2],\phi\in[0,\pi)\}$ and give its closure $\overline{M}$. Is $M$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, compactness

Sketch $M=\{re^{i\phi}:r\in(1,2],\phi\in[0,\pi)\}$ and give its closure $\overline{M}$. Is $M$ compact?

---

[image]

$\overline{M} = \{re^{i\phi}:r \in (1,2], \phi \in [0,\pi) \} \cup \{ re^{i\pi} \} \cup \{e^{i\phi}\} \cup \{ e^{i\pi} \}$.

$M$ is not compact as for example $[0, e^{i\pi}]\subseteq M^c$.

---

Is my understanding of this correct? If yes, does it need any more argumentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your picture is not correct. Since $\theta\in[0,\pi)$, it should be just the top half (also with $(1,2]$, but without $[-2,1)$).

The set $M$ is not closed because, for instance $1\in\overline M\setminus M$. But $\overline M$ is compact, since it is both closed and bounded.

Comment: So this would be correct, if I understand correctly? https://i.imgur.com/RxfbG1G.png

Comment: @math_mu Yes, that yould be correct.